# Problem with boost::bind, boost::function and boost::factory

Tags: c++, boost-bind, boost-function

I'm trying without success to use a boost::bind with a boost::factory

I have this class Zambas with 4 arguments (2 strings and 2 ints) and

```
class Zambas {

public:

Zambas(const std::string&, const std::string&,int z1=0,int z2=0) {    
      if (z1==z2){

      }
    }
};
```

inside other method i have the following call

```
boost::function<Zambas*()> f(boost::bind(boost::factory<Zambas*>(), std::string(""), std::string(""),_1,_2));
```

that fails with the following compiler error:

`bind.hpp:382: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘a[boost::_bi::storage3<A1, A2, boost::arg<I> >::a3_ [with A1 = boost::_bi::value<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, A2 = boost::_bi::value<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, int I = 1]]’`

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The `bind` function returns a two-argument functor because you bound the third and fourth parameters of your constructor to the placeholder values `_1` and `_2`. However, you're storing the result in a zero-argument `function` object.

I found [a reference from six years ago](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2004/12/9069.php) explaining that you can't omit parameters when you bind a function, *even if they're declared with default values*.

I think you have three options:

1. Provide actual `int` values in your call to `bind` instead of placeholders.
2. Change the declaration of `f` to indicate that it stores a two-argument function, and then always provide both values when you call it.
3. Bind the last two parameters to *variables*. See [*Delaying constants and variables*](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2004/12/9069.php) in the Boost.Lambda documentation. Then, you can set those variables to the same default values as the constructor declares. To use the default values, do nothing more. To specify non-default values, assign values to those variables before calling `f`.

The last option will probably just make your code harder to read without much benefit, so prefer one of the first two options instead.